# Use list cons operator (a :: b) as a function

Tags: function, f#, operator-keyword

F# lets you turn operators into functions by surrounding them with `(` `)`: for instance, `(+)` is of type `int -> int -> int`.

Is it possible to do this with the list cons operator, `::`?

It doesn't behave like a normal binary operator:

```
FSI> (::);;

  (::);;
  -^^

c:\temp\stdin(3,2): error FS0010: Unexpected symbol '::' in expression.
Expected ')' or other token.
```

And the `List.Cons` method takes a tuple; it's not curried.

(It's useful to be able to do this. For instance, you can use it to implement [map in terms of fold](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Fold)).

Comment: Can you just not write a small wrapper around `::` or `List.Cons`?

Comment: Ookay, this is really weird. You can just go `fun x y -> x :: y` but I have no idea why there is such mindless inconsistency - Maybe because `::` can be used in pattern matchings and is treated special? But that still would be no reason.

Comment: Interesting question. This works for concat `(@)` thought.

Comment: @leppie I could, but I don't have to for normal binary operators such as `(+)`

Comment: See my answer for "the reason".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Paraphrased from http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/permalink/11713/11713/ShowThread.aspx#11713

`(::)` is a discriminated union 'constructor' for the `list<'a> type`, and so raised the question of whether as a function value its arguments should be curried (like `+`) or tupled (like all DU constructors).  Either way seems fishy/unexpected to some people, so F# simply disallows the construct.

Of course you can always write e.g.

```
let cons x y = x :: y
```

and use `cons`, or just use a lambda `fun x y -> x::y`, if you want a "curried prefix function of two args" for this.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, no, you can't.  `::` is not an operator, but a "symbolic keyword" according to the language grammar (see section [3.6 of the spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597389)), as are `:?>` and a few others.  The language doesn't seem completely consistent here, though, since there are a few symbolic keywords which can be treated as though they were operators (at least `(*)` and `(<@ @>)`).

Answer (score 5):

`::` and `[]` can both be represented by `List<_>.Cons` and `List<_>.Empty` respectively.  Keep in mind though that the former takes a tuple as an argument.  These are here so lists can be created in languages other than F#.

```
> List.Cons(4, List.Empty);;
val it : int list = [4]

> 4::[];;
val it : int list = [4]

> List<int>.Cons(4, List<int>.Empty);;
val it : int list = [4]

> List.Cons;;
val it : 'a * 'a list -> 'a list = <fun:clo@24-7> //'

> List<int>.Empty;;
val it : int list = []
```

Comment: Thanks. I had a prolbem converting ML op:: to F# where (fun x y -> x :: y) failed to compile, but List<_>.Cons worked.